# When I'm inside an object, I can't see it's outside. How do I disable this?

Tags: modeling

What my problem is, is that once I go inside the model, the 'wall' or the outisde of the model becomes invisible. So, if you'd follow the pictures, you can see in the top picture that I can see the mouth clearly and actually the whole object. But once I go inside the mouth and I turn about 180 degrees, most of the model becomes invisible(mid picture). And if I move in the same direction as how I entered the mouth and enter the model via the mouth and exit the model via the occiput and turn about 180 degrees again, the whole model becomes visible again(bottom picture). I really wouldn't know how to fix this. By the way, I'm a beginner in Blender, so I'd like a detailed awnser.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have backface culling enabled? Select your object and look under `Material Properties > Settings > Backface Culling` if it is ticked.